# Create a page programatically with C# in SharePoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

Not sure if this is asked, but searching hasn't quite yielded what I'm looking for. I have a page layout already, what I need to do is programmatically create a page in the Pages library.

I'm fuzzy on the details, but somehow I think I will need to open the Layout, then stream it to a page and then save the page. I'm unsure how to go about this.

The page is context sensitive so I think I'll begin with using SPSite and SPWeb to get access to the lists.

What I'm unclear on is, how can I get the Layouts? I think I should be able to add a page somewhat like this:

```
 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb();


                    SPList Pages = web.Lists["Pages"];
                    SPListItemCollection splc = Pages.Items;


                    foreach (SPListItem spli in splc)
                    {
                        if (spli.Name == "lmIntraTopicsArticle")
                        {

                        }
                    }

                    SPListItem sli = splc.Add();
                    Pages.Update();
                    SPFolder PagesFolder = Pages.RootFolder;
                    byte[] layoutContents = new byte[20];
                    SPFile myNewPage = PagesFolder.Files.Add(PagesFolder.Url + "/TopicWindowArchive.aspx", layoutContents);
                    web.Update();
```

Now I need to figure out how to add content from a layout. Update in a few if I figure it out.

Thank you,

Comment: At this point I'm just down to figuring out how to access the layouts then pulling that in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to get a PublishingWeb object. That contains the layouts.

See [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/17/create-publishing-pages-sharepoint-2010-programmatically/) for an example

```
PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);

string pageName = “MyCustomPage.aspx”;

PageLayout[] pageLayouts = publishingWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts();

PageLayout currPageLayout = pageLayouts[0];

PublishingPageCollection pages = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages();

PublishingPage newPage = pages.Add(pageName,currPageLayout);

newPage.ListItem[FieldId.PublishingPageContent] = “This is my content”;

newPage.ListItem.Update();

newPage.Update();

newPage.CheckIn(“This is just a comment”);
```

Also [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981685/how-to-dynamically-switch-pagelayout-and-masterpage-of-sharepoint-publishing-pag/1167482#1167482)

Comment: Thank! That helped a lot. I inserted a foreach loop around the GetPageLayouts() to search for the correct one, but other than I kept the code.